# Warning: failed to open stream: Invalid argument in C:\xampp\htdocs\WWW\index.php on line 17

Tags: php, mysql, opencart2.x

I have error in my website,when i'm trying to migrate my project from server to localhost then its getting error in index.php and config.php below,

> Warning:
>
> require_once(/C:/xampp/htdocs/wwwC:/xampp/htdocs/www/system/startup.php):
>   failed to open stream: Invalid argument in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\www\index.php on line 17

```
require_once(DIR_SYSTEM . 'startup.php');
```

My config.php,

```
$root = '/C:/xampp/htdocs/www';
$url = 'http://localhost/www/';
$projectpath = '';
$path = str_replace("index.php","",str_replace($root, "",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
$url2= $url.$path;
$rootfolder = $root.$path;
define('HTTP_SERVER', $url2);// HTTPS define('HTTPS_SERVER', $url2);   

// DIR
define('ROOT_APPLICATION', $root .$projectpath);
define('PROJECT_PATH', $projectpath);
define('MAIN_URL', $url.$projectpath);
define('ROOT_URL', $url2);
define('DIR_APPLICATION', $rootfolder.'catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', $rootfolder.'system/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', $rootfolder.'catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', $rootfolder.'catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', $rootfolder.'system/config/');
define('DIR_IMAGE', $root.$projectpath.'image/');
define('DIR_CACHE', $rootfolder.'system/storage/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', $rootfolder.'system/storage/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', $rootfolder.'system/storage/logs/');
define('DIR_MODIFICATION', $rootfolder.'system/storage/modification/');
define('DIR_store', $rootfolder.'system/storage/');
define('TEMPLATE_PATH', $root.$projectpath);
```

Comment: i think the file startup.php is not in the folder or might be something problem with the constant **DIR_SYSTEM**. Please check the constant.

Comment: Ok,Thank you i will check.

Comment: hello,i didint get my error.after i check.

Comment: i think the value assigned for the variables **$root** in wrong. In the error occured for you, is **require_once(/C:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusellC:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusell/system/startup.php):** here the path is worng. There is no chance of this type of path. Please change the **$root** to a null and check it out.

Comment: Admin Panel not running getting same error and my website home page not working properly like my live server.

Comment: It will work after you correct the path credential. Please check with that.

Comment: After i removed $SERVER[ ' '] then its working but product url not working it goes to object not found.

Comment: how to correct path credentials please tell me path step by step

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this line of code is the problem:

```
$path = str_replace("index.php","",str_replace($root, "",$_SERVER['SCRIPT_FILENAME']));
```

it creates a full (absolute) path instead of a relative path.

adding it to:

```
$rootfolder = $root.$path; // '/C:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusell' . 'C:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusell/system/startup.php'
```

makes a double absolute path as you can see in the comments.

and that path doesn't exist.

#### Solution

a solution would be to just take the $path variable:

```
$rootfolder = $path; // 'C:/xampp/htdocs/ecompusell/system/startup.php'
```